# how to break out of the loop and print only once?

Tags: python

my loop is working well but it's printing several times, i only want one print.

this is my loop code:

```
currentEmployees = []
        found_match = False
        for event in events:
            currentEmployees.append(event['summary'])

        for i in range(3):
            event_inspecteur = row[i+1]
            if event_inspecteur not in currentEmployees:
                code here
                print('Nouveau RDV creer')
                event = service.events().insert(calendarId='primary', body=event).execute()
                break

            else:
                print('We cannot add an event at this moment : ')
                start = event['start'].get('dateTime', event['start'].get('date'))
                print(start, "Fabricant:" + event['description'], "Inspecteur: " + event['summary'], "Location: " + event['location'])
                pass
```

I wan't to print the `else` part only once. Instead this is what I get:

```
We cannot add an event at this moment : 
2020-05-03T16:00:00Z Fabricant:abc Inspecteur: Crihan, I M Location: xxx
We cannot add an event at this moment : 
2020-05-03T16:00:00Z Fabricant:abc Inspecteur: Crihan, I M Location: xxx
We cannot add an event at this moment : 
2020-05-03T16:00:00Z Fabricant:abc Inspecteur: Crihan, I M Location: xxx
```

Comment: Change `pass` to `break`

Comment: lol, that was easy. thank you @NathanWride

Comment: I think you should deindent your `else` so it applies to the loop, not to the `if`. Otherwise your loop is pointless.

Comment: @CNAS I added an alternate solution that may or not be helpful. If not then I'll delete it

Answer (score 1):

You just need to use your `found_match` variable to check if you have assigned an employee or not after the loop like this:

```
currentEmployees = []
for event in events:
    found_match = False
    currentEmployees.append(event['summary'])

    for i in range(3):
        event_inspecteur = row[i+1]
        if event_inspecteur not in currentEmployees:
            print('Nouveau RDV creer')
            event = service.events().insert(calendarId='primary', body=event).execute()
            currentEmployees.append(event_inspecteur)
            found_match = True
            break

    if not found_match:
        print('We cannot add an event at this moment : ')
        start = event['start'].get('dateTime', event['start'].get('date'))
        print(start, "Fabricant:" + event['description'], "Inspecteur: " + event['summary'], "Location: " + event['location'])
```

Comment: It doesnt work, because you have to kind of understand the reality of this code. This code is meant to create an appointment to google calendar API using python, and a MySQL database. A company is assigned to 3 different employees, if one employe is busy, the code check for the next one to see if he's available. I just realized that if I remove the pass, the code won't run to the 3rd employee if 1 and 2 are busy. Also, your new answer didn't worked because it created an appointment for the 3 employees. Thank you for your time and answers.. let me know if you can find something else!..

Comment: @CNAS I have edited the solution to so adds a match to currentEmployees, so it shouldn't double-up now. Is this any better?

Comment: Still not giving the results I need!

Answer (score 0):

Try using `break` instead of `pass`